# what interrupt Controller a guest OS use, find it

Tags: qemu, emulation

My host system is Linux. I am using qemu as an emulator. I want to know what interrupt controller is used by the guest OS. Other information also like what interrupts are called etc.

guide me in details

Answer (score 2):

Linux can use the PIC 8259, the simplest interrupt controller that has 2 banks of 8 pins. Then there is the APIC with 256 interrupt vectors that can be assigned to devices. You read the PCI memory for a given device to find out what interrupts it has been assigned for PIC and can tell a device to use a given ISR vector for APIC. Then there is MSI and MSI-X that use messages and not interrupts for potentially higher performance. hth